# requests.iter_content() thinks file is complete but it's not

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, truncated

This question differs from others that I have seen regarding `requests.iter_content()` in that `requests` seems to think that it has successfully reached the end of the file I am iterating over. In reality the file has been truncated and is incomplete. The file I am trying to process is a 17gb gzip to be enriched and stored inside a database. A browser can download the file just fine.

Why is this file not downloading all the way and why doesn't `requests` throw an exception if it can't download the whole file?

**Source Code: (updated - see edit)**

Here is my "reader" function - it is part of a multiprocessing script that is working with the data:

```
def patch_urllib3():
    """Set urllib3's enforce_content_length to True by default."""
    previous_init = urllib3.HTTPResponse.__init__
    def new_init(self, *args, **kwargs):
        previous_init(self, *args, enforce_content_length = True, **kwargs)
    urllib3.HTTPResponse.__init__ = new_init

def reader(target_url, data_queue, coordinator_queue, chunk_size):
    patch_urllib3() 
    #Using zlib.MAX_WBITS|32 apparently forces zlib to detect the appropriate header for the data
    decompressor = zlib.decompressobj(zlib.MAX_WBITS|32)
    #Stream this file in as a request - pull the content in just a little at a time
    #This should remain open until completion.
    with requests.get (target_url, stream=True) as remote_file:
        last_line="" #start this blank
        #Chunk size can be adjusted to test performance
        for data_chunk in remote_file.iter_content(chunk_size=4096):
            #Decompress the current chunk
            decompressed_chunk=decompressor.decompress(dns_chunk)
            #These characters are in "byte" format and need to be decoded to utf-8
            decompressed_chunk=decompressed_chunk.decode()
            #Append the "last line" to add any fragments from the last chunk - it is blank the first time around
            #This basically sticks line fragments from the last chunk onto the front of the current chunk.
            decompressed_chunk=last_line+decompressed_chunk
            #Run a split here; this is likely a costly step...
            data_chunk=list(decompressed_chunk.splitlines())
            #Pop the last line off the chunk since it isn't likely to be complete
            #We'll add it to the front of the next chunk
            last_line=dns_chunk.pop()
            data_queue.put(data_chunk)
            coordinator_queue.put('CHUNK_READ')
    #File is fully read so send the last line and let the reader exit:
    print("Sending last line.")
    data_queue.put(last_line)
    #Notify coordinator process of task completion
    coordinator_queue.put('READ_DONE')
```

**Additional Notes:**

- When the code runs it ends up pulling less data than what is contained in the full file.

  - This leaves me with a fragmented `last_line` at the end (which then breaks my data processing function).
  - I was under the impression that the `with` clause and `stream=True` argument would help prevent the session from closing prematurely.
- The full file should contain 1.8 billion rows

  - The script typically stops between 1 and 2 million rows.
- There are not any errors from the `requests` library when the request "completes".

  - Upon "completion" the console prints `Sending last line.` per my code sample
  - This confirms that the `with` clause has "successfully" completed.
- Error trapping in my other processes indicates a line fragment being sent since the only line in the final chunk is the residual data from the last request iteration.

**Update:**

I have found [a blog post that speaks directly to this issue](https://blog.petrzemek.net/2018/04/22/on-incomplete-http-reads-and-the-requests-library-in-python/). It appears that by default the `requests` package does not set the `urllib3` `enforce_content_length` option to true. There is no way to do this directly through `requests` and so one must "patch" the `urllib3` options prior to setting up the `requests` object. Note the `def patch_urllib3()` function [listed in this gituhub issue](https://github.com/getsentry/responses/issues/394). I have updated my source code to include this function and now I receive the following errors when the read stops prematurely:

> urllib3.exceptions.IncompleteRead: IncompleteRead(52079993 bytes read,
> 18453799085 more expected)
>
> urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection broken:
> IncompleteRead(52079993 bytes read, 18453799085 more expected)',
> IncompleteRead(52079993 bytes read, 18453799085 more expected))
>
> requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError: ('Connection broken:
> IncompleteRead(52079993 bytes read, 18453799085 more expected)',
> IncompleteRead(52079993 bytes read, 18453799085 more expected))

I am still working to see if there is a solution to these errors or some ability to resume the file download. I've tried sending another request and including `range` headers that start where the download ended previously but it seems that the interruption to the initial request is irrecoverable.